# Performance Test Automation Tool Stack

Tags: automated-testing

Please provide what a Performance Test Automation Tool Stack is.

Comment: why is it downvoted?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to know - what problem are you seeking to solve here?

Answer (score 3):

The most popular tools are listed below:

- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Yandex.Tank](https://tech.yandex.com/tank/)
- [HP LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/index.html)
- [NeoLoad](http://www.neotys.com/product/overview-neoload.html)

> Here are few comparisons of them:
>
> - [Grinder vs Gatling vs Tsung vs JMeter (September 2015)](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)
> - [LoadRunner vs Grinder vs JMeter (June 2006 not up to date anymore)](http://blackanvil.blogspot.com/2006/06/shootout-load-runner-vs-grinder-vs.html)
> - [JMeter vs NeoLoad vs JMeter (November 2017)](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php)

For more comprehensive list of tools also look at [www.opensourcetesting.org](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is repeated question. 
The Answer to this question can be found in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999552/which-is-the-best-performance-testing-tool-when-i-dont-know-the-client-applicati/31003937#31003937